# How to set the partition by and cluster by parameters in the BigQuery php API (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery)

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Below is the code to create a BigQuery table using the PHP API. How to set the PARTITION BY and CLUSTER BY parameters in the API?

```
$fields = array(
array('name' => 'row_id', 'type' => 'integer', 'mode' => 'required'),
array('name' => 'site_id', 'type' => 'integer', 'mode' => 'required'),
array('name' => 'article_id', 'type' => 'integer', 'mode' => 'required')
);

$client = new BigQueryClient([
'projectId' => $my_project_id,
'keyFilePath' => $my_credential_json_file
]);

$client->dataset($dataset_id)->createTable($table_name, [
'schema' => [
'fields' => $fields_array
]);
```

Comment: Please ask a clear question.

Comment: Hi @DV82XL hope my question is clear know. Thanks

Comment: Much better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create tables is to use DDL `CREATE TABLE` statement. Here is the documentation about `CLUSTER BY` clause in it: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#clustering_column_list

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it is clear now. Thanks